# class-like closure in python3 using locals

Tags: python, functional-programming, scheme, closures

I found this article look interesting
http://okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/oop-in-fp.txt

So I tried to write a class-like closure(just a toy) implemented in Python like this:

```
def clos(x,y):
    def getx():
        print(x)
    def gety():
        print(y)
    def setx(i):
        nonlocal x
        x = i
    def sety(i):
        nonlocal y
        y = i
    lc = locals()
    return lambda x,*y:lc[x](*y)

k=clos(1,2)
k("getx")
k("gety")
k("setx",2)
k("getx")
```

However, I think the `lc = locals()` looks clunky. But I can't use `return lambda x,*y:locals()[x](*y)` in the following sentence as it would construct a different environment.

Is there any trick to make it look more simple?

Comment: What is the reason for not just using a class?

Comment: I'm interested in implementing a class without using the keyword ``class``

Comment: That's easy; just use `type()`.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
return (lambda lc: lambda x,*y:lc[x](*y))(locals())
```